# Java 8: Get Operator-Function-Object with method reference

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

I wondered if there is a possibility in Java 8, to get the method references of the standard operators (+, -, <, >, ...).

I want to get it like `Foo::+` where Foo is some defined place where i can get it.
Since Java doesn't allow special characters in method names I don't think it's possible, is it?

If the way above doesn't exist: Is there some place where the standard operators are defined like `Foo::plus`?

I know there is the possiblity of defining it as lambda (`(x, y) -> x + y`), but in my opinion it could be more expressive in some cases with a method reference to the operator like it's possible in Haskell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [`int Integer.sum(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#sum-int-int-) and similar methods, which are indeed provided by the API.

There are many methods from your list missing, but it's common for the JDK not to provide the last inch of convenience because its size is enormous even without those.

If that's any consolation, each of my projects has a `Util` class where I dump tidbits such as these.

Comment: Operators like >, <, too? I don't know where to look.

Comment: Is there some place, where maybe all operators are defined? Some class with only static methods maybe of name `Ops` or something like that?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Ther's `Integer.compare`, but you'd still have to write some code to get boolean predicates.

Answer (score 1):

A clean way would be an `Operators` helper class that contains methods for all operators. Then you could use these methods as references. Of course, a standard library class would be nicer than an own helper class, but at least you can decide the name of that helper class, so you can choose a name that is most expressive to you.

Answer (score 0):

The standard operators only apply to primitives and boxed primitives, and you can't dynamically find which operators are applicable to the object in question.

Edit: If you want to know what method's you could call to perform standard operator functions, you can do a instanceof check to the comparable interface for the greater/less than or equals operators(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Comment: "The standard operators only apply to primitives and boxed primitives, and you can't dynamically find which operators are applicable to the object in question." I don't understand that. I think the compiler can find out, if the types are suitable. (Well, maybe my english is just too bad to understand it ;-) )

Comment: Ok, while implementing `<` I see what you mean. It's not possible to do `<` with the superclass `Number`.

Comment: The only operator that works on objects is ==. This is because it doesn't actually compare the objects but just the reference (the pointer if you're familiar with c++). So if 2 objects have the same contents, but they're not the same object instance, they're still not gonna return true on the == operator.